# How many counterexamples the Riemann Hypothesis, if false, can have?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Are there papers, which show, that there can not be infinite many counter-examples for the Riemann Hypothesis?
Can you give me references for these papers? I enjoy thinking and learning. I mean no harm; I am curious, I would like to know how the reality of Math is made.

Comment: "Forbidden" is a dubious choice of words in mathematics. I know only of a positive result: that at least 40% of the zeros of the Zeta function in the critical strip lie on the critical line (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalLine.html).

Comment: Please clarify the title. It seems that if RH is false, it is false "infinitely often".

Comment: "RH false" means there is at least one zero in the critical strip not on the critical line.  So the OP asks: if there is one of these, is it known that this implies there must be infinitely many of them?

Comment: I don't think there exists this result. The only case I can think that could prove such a claim is if we show that the 100% of the non trivial zeros lie on the critical line and this happens "in the best possible case", that is, if $N(T)-N_{0}(T)=O(1)$.